# setState() causing props to be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm brand new to React and am tinkering with some Firebase stuff. I'm trying to load in some data from Firebase, filter through some of it, and then set my current state to that data. For some reason on the code below, calling `setState` causes the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Activity from './ActivityList'

class ActivityList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        activities: []
      }

      let app = this.props.db.database().ref('activities');

      app.on('value', function(snapshot) {

        this.handleData(snapshot.val())

      }.bind(this))
    }

    handleData(values) {

        let category = this.props.category

        let filtered = values.filter(function(item) {
          return item.categories.includes(category)
        })

        console.log(filtered)

        this.setState({activities: filtered})

    }

    render() {
        let activityNodes = this.state.activities.map((activity) => {
          return (
            <Activity activity= {activity} />
            )
      });
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
             {activityNodes}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In my code, I am passing in firebase in `props.db`. I've also (hopefully) isolated the problem to `setState`, because my `console.log(filtered)` call works as intended, meaning on the first "pass", `prop/props.db` was definitely defined. I'm guessing that this has something to do with the non-blocking nature of `setState`, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this would cause the value of prop to be `undefined`.

Edit: Initialization code for `db` as requested:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var config = {
      apiKey:,
      authDomain:,
      databaseURL:,
      projectId:,
      storageBucket:,
      messagingSenderId: 
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

  }
```

This is then passed into a `Category` component:

`<CategoryList db={firebase}/>`

Which then passes it into the above `ActivityList` component:

`<ActivityList db={this.props.db}/>`

Again, even in the `ActivityList` component, it seems like it is reading from the database successfully until I call `setState`.

Comment: Is `this.props.db` undefined ?

Comment: Please show us the intitialization code for the db prop and how you pass it to this component. (remove your firebase credentials before)

Comment: @Rayon this.props.db is definitely not undefined, because the `console.log(filtered)` is reading from the database and outputting correctly (likewise, I can do `console.log(snapshot.val())` and get correct output)

Comment: @Daniel main posted updated with information

Comment: I am confused. I see that you access this.props.db in the constructor, but nowhere else. So why does it access this.props.db somewhere else during the lifetime of your classes instance?

Comment: @Daniel I'm confused about this too...

Comment: are you sure that this error message occurs on this line? The stacktrace should show you what line the error occured. The stacktrace would be great

Comment: The stacktrace indeed points to this line:  `let app = this.props.db.database().ref('activities');
`

Comment: @Daniel As a small development, this may be a problem with my render function, specifically the mapping? When I replace `return ( <Activity activity= {activity} /> )` with `return ( <p> Hello </p> )`, the error does not happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156203/discussion-between-daniel-and-thevises).

Comment: try using `let app = props.db.database().ref('activities');` rather than `let app = this.props.db.database().ref('activities');`

Comment: Try putting the firebase subscription code in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). That's the canonical way for loading data & doing _big_ things. Perhaps the `'value'` callback is called immediately because it has data from Firebase, and that triggers a `setState`, which triggers a `render` - all in the same tick. But without the component being properly initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

In chat we found that he was importing something wrong. That was missing in his question's post.

```
import Activity from './ActivityList'
```

Now his map function created ActivityList Components instead of Actitvity Components.

But it should be:

```
import Activity from './Activity'
```